# How To Use Http Push With Python Server And Android Client?

Tags: java, python, http, push

I have a simply Http Server written by Python's BaseHTTPRequestHandler.
With a client written by Java in Android with HttpClient.
And I want to push data from python server to client java:
So I try to make a while True loop at server, A few piece of server's code:

```
def do_POST(self):
    # receive POST data from client
    # ...
    # Then I want to keep alive this connection
    self.send_response(200)
    while True:
        self.send_response(200)
        time.sleep(5)

And HttpClient and MultipartEntity for java Client:
    protected String doInBackground() {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.104:8089");

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("audio"));
        byte []dataByte = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        entity.addPart("data", new ByteArrayBody(dataByte, "data"));
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // Please see This log will never print because blocked above
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Server response");
    }
```

I want to receive server's response contiguously after httpClient.execute().
But I am blocked at the last source of client because the While True loop at server.

I guess httpClient.execute() is waiting for the http socket closing?
Can you please help me for how to handle this situation?
I have searched the push technology and seems long pulling is another way to push.

But I think push is more better solution for my situation.

Comment: Hi! I guess http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html is not a viable solution in your case, right? Can you show a little more of your client & server code?

Comment: Dear Giupo: Yes, you are right, maybe that's not my solution. I want to send / receive audio / text data to / from client via HTTP in a LAN. I don't want to use TCP Socket directly because it's much too complex on coding. I think HTTP protocol is more efficient but seems coding is too difficult. Can you help on this? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the server side code, where:

```
while True:
    self.send_response(200)
    time.sleep(5)
```

The `do_Post` method is an handler, and the self.send_response(200) just set the HTTP status; but it doesn't actually send something over the wire. And you hang in there forever.

I think that you should review completely the architecture of your app, server side and client side(I maybe wrong, but `DefaultHttpClient` isn't deprecated [1] ?

Have you considered using websockets : https://github.com/koush/android-websockets ?

[1] http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Comment: So thanks for your comments and I use Autobahn websocket to solve my problems. Thanks for indicating me the right direction. You are great.